# How to use getSystemCpuLoad() in JMX

Tags: java, jmx

Hi i cant able to use getProcessCpuTime() or getProcessCpuLoad() or getSystemCpuLoad() in my java program. I used like below.

```
ManagementFactory. getOperatingSystemMXBean().getProcessCpuTime();
```

also like this

```
( (OperatingSystemMXBean) getOperatingSystemMXBean() ).getProcessCpuTime()
```

But its showing error like method getProcessCpuTime() is not found. I included the following header files. Is that enough or i need to use any more.?

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to use these methods. am using jdk1.6. And my code is below

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class printUsage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

System.out.println("getCpuProcessTime()" + " = " + operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime());
System.out.println("getCpuProcessTime()" + " = " + operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad());
System.out.println("getCpuProcessTime()" + " = " + operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuLoad());
}

}
```

Comment: please refer the code i posted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

import following one

```
 import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
```

Not

```
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
```

Use following code.

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

I am getting valid results with this code.

Comment: ya its working fine for getProcessCpuTime() but its again showing error if i try for getSystemCpuLoad() and for getProcessCpuTime()..

Comment: There is no method getSystemCpuLoad in the docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html.

Comment: i found those methods in the following link [link](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime())

Comment: Those are jdk8 methods and your jdk is 6. If you want to call that method, you need to upgrade your jdk to 8.

Comment: How to upgrade.. Can i copy that zip file can replace it in the jdk1.6 folder..? Or can u send the exact link?

Comment: You need to download jdk from Oracle website then use it as your jdk instead of jdk6. http://jdk8.java.net/. Remember this is not released officially yet.

Comment: Is it possible to get it as zip file am gettimg oly .exe file

Comment: Thank you for your kind details. Can you please tell me how you found that it will work only from jdk8. Because it will help me to solve by my self in future..

Comment: Goto method details by clicking on method, there you will see since. My mistake actually it is from 1.7 onwards. I overlooked it.

Comment: If you are happy with answer, accept it by clicking tick mark right beside my answer. Any other quetions you may post as new question.

Comment: So kind of u.. thank you very much. I upvoted and accepted it as right answer. But my actual need is to find the load in the remote system. I will be more thankful and appreciate if provide answer for my existing post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197824/how-to-find-the-maximum-amount-of-load-that-a-c-p-u-can-bear)

Comment: Thank you! I will check as soon as I get sometime.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my existing post and posted newly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219237/how-to-find-the-c-p-u-load-percentage-of-c-p-u-utilization-in-the-slave-node). I hope you can answer for this post easly. If you have free time please go through [my post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219237/how-to-find-the-c-p-u-load-percentage-of-c-p-u-utilization-in-the-slave-node) once

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on the following javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

See what methods are defined for OperatingSystemMXBean. Your problem is that you are looking for methods defined in `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` into `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`.

Package `com.sun` is mostly for internal use of java creators, not for application developers. You should use classes from package `java.lang.management` and refer to appropriate API doc.